# Construct a grammar that generates this language

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammar

This is a homework problem.  The problem is:

Find a grammar that generates this language:

L = {w: |w| mod 3 ≠ |w| mod 2} over alphabet Σ = {a}.

The transitions I came up with are:

S -> Baa

B -> aaa | Baaa | lambda

But this doesn't take into account 4.  I've been playing with it for awhile and can't seem to figure out in what direction to go to make this happen.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think the best first step here is to start by forgetting about grammars and just ponder, as a matter of number theory: Which numbers is it that satisfy $n\bmod 3\ne n\bmod 2$? (Hint: Chinese Remainder Theorem followed by case analysis)

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  Here's what I've come up with:
S -> Baa | Caaaa | Caaaaaa
, B -> aaa | Baaa | lambda
, C -> aaaaaa | Caaaaaa | lambda.
Does this work as a solution? I'm not sure if I can have different start states like that and generate the language piecemeal.

Comment: x @Caulibrot: Yes that looks like it works. But you seem to have a bad habit of writing $$ L\to A\mid LA \mid \Lambda $$ whenever you want $L$ to expand to a list of zero or more $A$s. It is sufficient (and uambiguous) to write $$ L \to \Lambda \mid LA $$ If you want _at least_ one $A$, then you could write $$ L \to A \mid LA $$ but having all three production hints that you don't really grok how the two constructions work. I'd advice taking some time to think them through.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks.  That is a simpler way of writing it.

Answer (score 1):

An other way (than the nice comment of @Henning Makholm) is to simply remember the rest in the modulo operation.

Formally let $\{R_{i,j}\mid i\in\{0,1\}, j\in\{0,1,2\}\}$ be the set of non terminals. $R_{i,j}$ represent that so far the word produced is such that $|w|\ mod\ 2=i$ and $|w|\ mod\ 3 =j$.

The starting non terminal is $R_{0,0}$ and we have the folowing rules in G: forall $i\in\{0,1\}, j\in\{0,1,2\}$ there is the rule:

$$R_{i,j}\to a R_{i',j'}$$
with $i'=(i+1)\ mod\ 3$ and $j'=(j+1)\ mod\ 3$.

And for all $i\neq j$ there is the rule 
$$R_{i,j}\to \epsilon$$